# Pumping Windows Messages During Long Operation?

Tags: c#, message-pump

I'm getting the following message on a big operation that I'm running:

> The CLR has been unable to transition
>   from COM context 0x1fe458 to COM
>   context 0x1fe5c8 for 60 seconds. The
>   thread that owns the destination
>   context/apartment is most likely
>   either doing a non pumping wait or
>   processing a very long running
>   operation without pumping Windows
>   messages. This situation generally has
>   a negative performance impact and may
>   even lead to the application becoming
>   non responsive or memory usage
>   accumulating continually over time. To
>   avoid this problem, all single
>   threaded apartment (STA) threads
>   should use pumping wait primitives
>   (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and
>   routinely pump messages during long
>   running operations.

How do I send windows messages so that this error will no longer occur on long operations?

Comment: any final solution with full source code ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what the context is - are you performing some long-running task on the UI thread of a WinForms or WPF app? If so, don't do that - use `BackgroundWorker`, or run the task on the thread pool or a new thread directly (possibly using `Control.Invoke/BeginInvoke` or `Dispatcher` if you need to update the UI). If your big operation *uses* the COM component which is complaining, it'll be harder...

Comment: Yes, this is in a WinForm (sorry for not specifying that in the OP). I will try implementing this code in a background worker, thanks!

Comment: Finished implementing this, worked like a charm, thanks again!

Comment: @Jon Skeet Could you please elaborate on the COM component part? We have multiple threads accessing COM object and this leads to the OPs issue.

Comment: @odyodyodys: It sounds like we'll need more information about the COM component you're using - in particular, which threading model it uses.

Comment: I have a thread processing a large amount of data, while the UI waits for progress messages. It sounds like I am doing it right, yet the debugger throws this messages.  What should I be doing in the UI thread while waiting for messages?

Comment: @James: It sounds like you should create a new question to show what you're doing.

Answer (score 7):

As I know this thing happens with attached debugger only. You will never get this exception in production.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't since the message is produced by a VS debugger's snap-in. Still, this fact doesn't remove the underlying problem the message warns of.

Comment: Thanks, I too noticed that my debugger shows this warning even when my UI is completely responsive at that moment (I even have a progress bar for my background task which I run using `Task.Run`, and the progress bar is alive and being animated, but still this exception is shown by Visual Studio. Maybe in my case it has something to do with the fact that I'm using WebBrowser element on my Windows form...

Answer (score 4):

If this happens inside a debugger it may be due to the ContextSwitchDeadlock MDA, which you can turn off (use the Exceptions window in Visual Studio). However, it is indicative of a larger problem -- you should not perform long-running operations on your UI thread.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to use [Application.DoEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx) in these scenarios. I don't know whether that will work in your situation though. It requires a reference to System.Windows.Forms but will also work in Console Apps.

Alternatively you can try multi-threading your apps.

Comment: Application.DoEvents is almost always the *wrong* solution here, IMO. There may be some edge cases where it's needed, but if it's just "I'm performing a long-running operation which really shouldn't be in the UI thread" then moving it off the UI thread is the right solution.

Comment: I agree entirely. I've not seen the error message recently, but I do vaguely recall that I've seen it not just on the UI thread. I _think_ I've seen it on long running COM requests but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The traditional win32 method is:

```
void PumpMessages()
{
    MSG msg;
    for( ;; ) {
        if( !PeekMessage( &msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) ) {
            return;
        }
        if( msg.message == WM_QUIT ) {
            s_stopped = true;
            return;
        }
        TranslateMessage( &msg );
        DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }
}
```

But I gather that you are using .NET.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this when switching from a WinForms project to a ConsoleApp project. The `Main()` method in `Program.cs` had an unnecessary `[STAThread]` attribute leftover from the WinForms template. Removing the attribute made the error go away.

Answer (score 0):

You should process your long running operation on a separate thread to avoid freezing up the UI. This will also resolve the problem above

Answer (score -1):

I know this was asked years ago, but hoping this will help others down the road. If you don't want to worry about doing a background worker, or pumping messages, a simple workaround is simply updating something on the UI. For example, I have a tool that only I use, so I don't care if it uses the UI thread. So I simply update a textbox.text on the UI to whatever I'm working on. here is a snippet of the code. This is a very hacky, and probably incorrect way to do it professionally, but it works.

```
for (int i = 0; i < txtbxURL.LineCount; i++)
{
    mytest.NavigateTo(mytest.strURL);
    mytest.SetupWebDoc(mytest.strURL);
    strOutput = mytest.PullOutPutText(mytest.strURL);
    strOutput = mytest.Tests(strOutput);
    mytest.CheckAlt(mytest.strURL);
    mytest.WriteError(txtbxWriteFile.Text);
    txtblCurrentURL.Text = mytest.strURL;
    //This ^^^ is what is being updated, which keeps the thread from throwing the exception noted above.
}
```